# Type for gapi.savetoandroidpay

Tags: typescript, android-pay, google-api-js-client, google-pay, typescript-types

I am trying to use Google Pay Passes with Typescript. There is a package to define the type: `npm install --save @types/gapi` but I don't have any method to use

```
gapi.savetoandroidpay.render("dom-container",{
  "jwt": "JWT",
  "onsuccess": "successHandler",
  "onfailure": "failureHandler"
});
```

[Here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/reference/s2w-reference#gapi.savetoandroidpay.render-function)

Am I using the wrong package or is this missing?

Comment: Most likely, type declarations haven't been updated to include this method. Declare it yourself and then creative a pr to definitely typed that adds it

Answer (score 0):

The `@types/gapi` package does not contain definitions to Google Pay implementations such as `gapi.savetoandroidpay` (as of Nov-26-2019).

Until the types are updated, I'd suggest declaring `gapi` as a type in your `global.d.ts`, or the TypeScript file where you use `gapi.savetoandroidpay.render()`.

**sample.ts**

```
declare var gapi: any;

const init=()=>{
  gapi.savetoandroidpay.render("dom-container",{
     "jwt": "JWT",
     "onsuccess": "successHandler",
     "onfailure": "failureHandler"
  });
}
```

Important to note that will only suppress type errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following type definition :

```
declare namespace gapi {}
declare namespace gapi.savetoandroidpay {
  type ButtonHeight = "small" | "standard";
  type ButtonSize = "matchparent" | undefined;
  type ButtonTextSize = "large" | undefined;
  type ButtonTheme = "dark" | "light";

  type SuccessHandler = (detail: { walletObjectIds: string[] }) => void;
  type FailureHandler = (error: Error) => void;
  type ProvideJwtHandler = () => string;

  interface ButtonOptions {
    jwt: string;
    height?: ButtonHeight;
    size?: ButtonSize;
    textsize?: ButtonTextSize;
    theme?: ButtonTheme;

    onSuccess?: SuccessHandler;
    onFailure?: FailureHandler;
    onProvideJwt?: ProvideJwtHandler;
  }

  function render(domId: string | Element, options: ButtonOptions): void;
}
```

You can this to a `gapi.savetoandroidpay.d.ts` file on your project.

This type definition originally came from https://github.com/google-pay/save-to-google-pay-button/blob/main/src/lib/button-manager.ts